# How to add a polygon on google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, dart

I'm using google_maps_flutter plugin to use google maps. I want to draw a polygon on google maps with coordinates taken from the user. The coordinates taken are type of 'Position' object.

I have already tried using map_view plugin to draw polygons. But it didn't work for me.

This is the code snippet where the coordinates are being taken.

```
Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator();
StreamSubscription<Position> _positionStreamSubscription;
final List<Position> _positions = <Position>[];

void _toggleListening() {
if (_positionStreamSubscription == null) {
  const LocationOptions locationOptions =
      LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.best, distanceFilter: 10);
  final Stream<Position> positionStream =
      Geolocator().getPositionStream(locationOptions);
  _positionStreamSubscription = positionStream.listen(
      (Position position) => setState(() => _positions.add(position)));
  _positionStreamSubscription.pause();
}

setState(() {
  if (_positionStreamSubscription.isPaused) {
    _positionStreamSubscription.resume();
  } else {
    _positionStreamSubscription.pause();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you can convert the coordinates of your `Position` objects to `LatLng` objects, then you can use [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) itself to draw polygons. You can see that [one of its parameters](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/lib/src/google_map.dart#L40) allows for [Polygons](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/lib/src/polygon.dart#L36). So just building upon the example from google_maps_flutter, we'll first setup our polygon:

```
Set<Polygon> myPolygon() {
  List<LatLng> polygonCoords = new List();
  polygonCoords.add(LatLng(37.43296265331129, -122.08832357078792));
  polygonCoords.add(LatLng(37.43006265331129, -122.08832357078792));
  polygonCoords.add(LatLng(37.43006265331129, -122.08332357078792));
  polygonCoords.add(LatLng(37.43296265331129, -122.08832357078792));

  Set<Polygon> polygonSet = new Set();
  polygonSet.add(Polygon(
      polygonId: PolygonId('test'),
      points: polygonCoords,
      strokeColor: Colors.red));

  return polygonSet;
}
```

Then just provide it to the GoogleMap widget.

```
GoogleMap(
  polygons: myPolygon(),
  mapType: MapType.normal,
  initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller.complete(controller);
  },
),
```

This will draw a small triangle near the GooglePlex.

For more information on this feature, you can refer to the Android documentation of [Maps SDK Shapes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/shapes). The API usage should be same, if not similar, so you can use it as a guideline.